# Cannot login elasticseach install via docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I setup elasticsearch using Dockerfile but I cannot login via elastic/changeme default user. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.4.2

ENV discovery.type="single-node"
ENV bootstrap.memory_lock=true
ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
ENV xpack.security.enabled=true


EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

How can I fix that. Please help me

Comment: Can you try with `ENV ELASTIC_PASSWORD=example`

Comment: @Adiii I thought this is env for paid version?

Comment: I think its for docker environment https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-isnt-my-elastic-password-environment-variable-in-docker-compose-yml-setting/105299